# PHPmailer smtp error with OVH, settings correct and work in mail app

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to get phpmailer to handle contact requests on my website but no matter what I try I get errors. The following is the code I'm using. The SMTP server, login and password all work perfectly in Thunderbird.

```
<html>
<body>

<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p style="font-family:verdana">
Thank you, <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?> <?php echo $_POST["lname"]; ?>, for your message!<br>
We will contact you shortly on : <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</p>
<a href="../../index.html">
<img src="../../assets/images/logo-medium.jpg">
</a>

<?php 

//require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$errors = '';
$myemail = '****@****.com';
$mypassword = '*******';

if(empty($_POST['fname'])  ||
   empty($_POST['lname']) ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['subject']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Erreur: All fields are required!";
}
$name = $_POST['fname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lname'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = 'From : ' . $name . '\n Concerning : ' . $_POST['subject'] . '\n\n' . $_POST['message']  ;
$subject = 'Request from site : ' . $_POST['subject'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail-> isSMTP();
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail-> AuthType = 'LOGIN';
$mail-> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail-> SMTPHost = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
$mail->Host = 'ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465';
$mail-> SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail-> Port ='465';
$mail-> isHTML();
$mail-> UserName=$myemail;
$mail-> Password=$mypassword;   
$mail-> SetFrom = $myemail;
$mail-> Subject = $subject;
//$mail-> AddAddress($myemail);
$mail-> AddAddress('*****@****.com');
$mail -> Body = $message;

if( empty($errors))
{
    $mail -> Send();
}
//else
//print $errors;

?>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

In thunderbird the SMTP settings are port 465, connection security SSL/TLS and authentication method is normal password.

The Debug output when I submit the form is:

```
2018-06-27 07:59:17 Connection: opening to ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 Connection: opened 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 ssl0.ovh.net player732 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.*****.com 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-player732.ha.ovh.net 250-SIZE 104857600 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 8BITMIME 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-06-27 07:59:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2018-06-27 07:59:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 SMTP ERROR: Username command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 Connection: closed 
2018-06-27 07:59:19 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried enabling and disabling different options for the AUthtype, SMTPAuth etc. but did not get any better results.

Is there something else to change or an alternative to phpmailer that might work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
$mail-> UserName=$myemail;
```

Should be:

```
$mail->Username=$myemail;
```

The giveaway there is the empty command after `AUTH LOGIN`, which tells you that the `Username` property must be empty.

It always helps to base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer - you've used something very old, and you're also using an old version of PHPMailer, which never helps.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Full disclosure: the only tutorial that I could find that _seemed_ to work required an older version of PHPMailer and I copied the code from that and still ended up messing it up.

Comment: That's one of the hassles of maintaining PHPMailer - it's been around for so long (since 2001) that there is a ton of stuff out there that's many years out of date - always [go to the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).